# Edges with same source and target in Gephi?

Tags: graph-theory, gephi

I want to draw a graph with Gephi, my nodes are countries and my edges correspond to trade exchanges between countries, but I have an additional information which is the exchanged product. If two countries trade different products, I happen to have several edges between two given nodes (the goal is to color them accordingly to the product). Weight is proportional to exchanged quantity.

For example I have the following edges :

`source target  label   weight

   104    0      22      0.18

    64    0      22      0.18

   120    0      22      0.12

   120    0      31      0.09`

But Gephi selects one of the edge and sums the weights...

[image]

If I choose id myself to make him undestand that even if I have the same source and target, I can have different edges, he still doesn't understand...

`id       source  target    label   weight

104_0_22    104     0        22      0.18

64_0_22      64     0        22      0.18

120_0_22    120     0        22      0.12

120_0_31    120     0        31      0.09`

I don't paste the picture but it is the same exactly..

Do somebody know how to handle that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is to have *multiple edges* between nodes. This is not supported at all in Gephi, as being said [here](https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?p=9245). As [this post](https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?p=8132#p8132) suggests you can use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) and [ORA](http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/projects/ora/). I have also seen that [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org) also allows multiple edges between nodes.

Comment: Good to know, thanks ! Which of these  would you recomwould for network with world maps? (Gephi has very useful plugins for this purpose)

Comment: That's a tough one! It cannot be done in any of the three! It seems the best solution is to use a bit of programming instead, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647537/using-geo-coordinates-as-vertex-coordinates-in-the-igraph-r-package) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915266/drawing-a-graph-with-networkx-on-a-basemap)

Comment: I know igraph and networkx, just wanted to try some dataviz tool, thanks a lot for your time!