# Connecting locations on map with Python with data illustrated

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to illustrate the density of flights from says Melbourne to other cities in Australia on a map. Ideally, we would have arrows (connecting a city to the others) with their thick demonstrate the number of flights in a day from one city to the others. Do we have a lib for this job?

Many thanks in advance for your inputs.

Kind regards,
HH

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic on SO. But take a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org). There are a few Python modules for it, eg [graphviz](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html), but for simple things it's easy enough to generate DOT files directly without using a 3rd-party module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data in form of nodes and edges (basically a graph DB), then you can use the following link:

[Drawing a graph with NetworkX on a Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915266/drawing-a-graph-with-networkx-on-a-basemap)

You can achieve your goal of 1) showing arrows/directions by using a directed graph and 2) thickness by using weights as the count of inwards/outwards directed flights

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your inputs. I've decided to go with simple arrow function with some pie charts as below. To produce this map, I employed:
- basemap
- plt.arrow
- plt.text
- plt.plot
- and a customised pie chart helper developed by Thomas Lecocq (http://www.geophysique.be/2010/11/26/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-06-real-case-pie-charts/)

The tricky part is to specify the starting and ending points of the arrows for a neat layout. Willing to provide more details upon request. Below I cite the pie chart helper:

```
def draw_pie(ax,ratios, X, Y, size):
N = len(ratios)
xy = []
start = 0.
colors=['#08298A','none']
for ratio in ratios:
    x = [0] + np.cos(np.linspace(2*math.pi*start,2*math.pi*(start+ratio), 30)).tolist()
    y = [0] + np.sin(np.linspace(2*math.pi*start,2*math.pi*(start+ratio), 30)).tolist()
    xy1 = zip(x,y)
    xy.append(xy1)
    start += ratio
plt.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = .7
plt.rcParams['patch.edgecolor']='#D0C4C1'
for i, xyi in enumerate(xy):
    ax.scatter([X],[Y] , marker=(xyi,0), s=size, facecolor=colors[i],zorder=5,alpha=.6, lw=.7 )
```

[image]

Thanks again. Cheers.

HH

Answer (score 0):

Sankey diagrams, using python a possibility seems to be the following:

http://matplotlib.org/api/sankey_api.html

Hope this helps :)